# Canceling publishing app to Google play store

Tags: android, upload, publish

I updated Promo Video for my app (adding video, not UPLOADING any NEW version of apk) and accidentally clicked "saved and published". Does this mean that my users will see a notification like "update new app" and they will update(meanwhile no new apk file is uploaded) or it just simply adds a promo video to my app. Either way how can I cancel if I accidentally upload the wrong version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry. Your users will only see a message about an upgrade when you have actually uploaded and published a new APK in the "APK" section.

Any changes you make to the "Store listing" section (including a promo video) will only update your play store listing. So people will only see the update when they visit your app's page on the Play Store. They don't get a notification.

Comment: Oh!! Thanks sir!!! I was really worried. Phew!!! But how about uploading wrong apk file? Any way to cancel it?

Comment: Nope. AFAIK The only way to undo the publishing of a bad APK is to upload and publish a newer one.

Comment: OK I got it. Thanks ^^

Comment: The update notice goes to your installed app users when the `android:versionCode` increases in the manifest file. You need to increase that `versionCode` before you can upload a new version.